# Android Volley getting Error Response using WCF Service on localhost

Tags: android, wcf, iis, android-volley, genymotion

I'm trying to consume a WCF RESTful Service hosted in IIS on Android using Volley. I have the next code:

```
private static final String URL_BASE = "http://10.0.3.2/SimpleRESTServiceCRUD/BookService.svc";
private static final String URL_JSON = "/Books";

List<Book> items;
JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;

public BookAdapter(Context context)
{
    super(context,0);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL_BASE + URL_JSON,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    items = parseJson(response);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Error on JSON response: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            }
    );
}
```

But when I'm debugging always get `new Response.ErrorListener()` BUT never gets into:

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Error on JSON response: " + error.getMessage());

}
```

So I can't know what happened!! I'm using Genymotion Emulator, so I tried this Uris:

```
http://192.168.56.1/SimpleRESTServiceCRUD/BookService.svc
http://10.0.3.2/SimpleRESTServiceCRUD/BookService.svc
```

I even used the Mobile Browser to see if it's working, and I actually could get to the service.

If anyone could give me a hand I will really appreciate.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your request has not been sent to the WCF Service, because you don't have the following line:

```
requestQueue.add(jsArrayRequest);
```

So, update your code as the following:

```
public BookAdapter(Context context)
{
    super(context,0);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL_BASE + URL_JSON,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    items = parseJson(response);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Error on JSON response: " + error.getMessage());

                }
            }
    );

    requestQueue.add(jsArrayRequest);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @BNK!!!! that was the problem. After I modfied my code based on your answer, I had Error 307, but I changed the location of the WCF App in the IIS and that fixed it. Thank you!